# Select Value not Init in AngularJs and JQueryMobile

Tags: angularjs, jquery-mobile

i have a html code like that

```
<select id="selectCatagoryFood" data-role="listview" data-native-menu="true"
                ng-options="foodCatagory as foodCatagory.Description for foodCatagory in foodCatagories"
                ng-init=""
                ng-model="foodCatagory"
                ng-change="changeFoodCatagory(foodCatagory)">
                </select>
```

for getting data from `AngularJs` and `JayData` but after getting data `select dropdown` not selected value by default it show empty. what should i write in `ng-init` attribute

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can either preset `ng-model="foodCatagory"` in the controller, for example:

```
$scope.foodCatagory = $scope.foodCatagories[0];
```

Or use ng-init like this:

```
ng-init="foodCatagory = foodCatagories[0]"
```

Note that if you load your `foodCatagories` asynchronously the data will most likely not be available when the directive compiles, which means `ng-init` will not work.

Since jQuery Mobile uses additional DOM elements to show and handle the select, you will need to tell it to refresh itself when the data has loaded and you have set the selected value.

You can for example write a directive to handle it:

```
app.directive('selectMenuRefresh', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
      var unbindWatcher = scope.$watch(attrs.ngModel, function(newValue, oldValue) {
        if (newValue && oldValue === undefined) {
          element.selectmenu('refresh');
          unbindWatcher();
        }
      });
    }
  };
});
```

And put it on the select element:

```
<select id="selectCatagoryFood" select-menu-refresh data-role="listview" data-native-menu="true" ng-options="foodCatagory as foodCatagory.Description for foodCatagory in foodCatagories" ng-model="foodCatagory" ng-change="changeFoodCatagory(foodCatagory)"></select>
```

This directive uses a `$watch` to detect when the `ngModel` changes. If there is a newValue (which there will be when `$scope.foodCatagory = $scope.foodCatagories[0];` is performed) and the oldValue is `undefined` (which it will be the first time when the first select option is empty), it will call refresh on the select element. It will also unbind the `$watch`. Modify after your needs.

Example: http://plnkr.co/edit/GLelHd?p=preview

Note: Make sure that jQuery and jQuery Mobile is loaded before AngularJS.

Comment: I added like this `ng-init="foodCatagory = foodCatagories[0]"` but it has no effects

Comment: My guess is that you are loading foodCatagories asynchronously. I have updated my answer.

Comment: `<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.2/jquery.mobile-1.3.2.min.css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.2/jquery.mobile-1.3.2.min.js"></script>`
Run your example by adding these there headers thensmae issue arises

Comment: I apologize, I spaced out on the jQuery Mobile part. I have updated my answer once again.

Comment: Can we use angularjs search in this? 
`<input id="searchFood" type="text" ng-model="searchText">`
  like that

Comment: THanks for the directive, worked very nicely for me.