# JQueryMobile select element not working within AngularJs ng-switch directive

Tags: angularjs, jquery-mobile

I have this HTML:

```
<div ng-switch on="MyViewType">
  <div ng-switch-when="B">
    <select id="selectCatagoryFood2" data-role="listview" data-native-menu="true" ng-options="foodCatagory as foodCatagory.Description for foodCatagory in foodCatagories" ng-model="foodCatagory" ng-change="changeFoodCatagory(foodCatagory)">
    </select>
  </div>
</div>
```

The select appears empty and do nothing if I select another value.

Example (the first "select" works correctly, but the second doesn’t show selected value): http://plnkr.co/edit/yrXa70?p=preview

The problem is similar to this other post, but this solution doesn’t work (the “Refresh” launches an exception).

[Select Value not Init in AngularJs and JQueryMobile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19609551/select-value-not-init-in-angularjs-and-jquerymobile)

I think the problem is that this directive (ng-switch) removes and adds elements from the DOM and JQuery Mobile loses some objects created in the initializations of the elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Code from your example:

```
var unbindWatcher = scope.$watch(attrs.ngModel, function(newValue, oldValue) {
        if (newValue && oldValue === undefined) {
          element.selectmenu('refresh');
          unbindWatcher();
        }
      });
```

The `element.selectmenu('refresh');` will be called when `ngModel` (which is the selected option) gets a new value and the old value is undefined.

This will work for the first select because it will:

1. First get rendered and initialized as a select menu by jQuery Mobile
2. Later get new data and be refreshed

However, in the second case, the HTML inside `<div ng-switch-when="B">` will not get rendered until `MyViewType` is actually `B`, which is at the same time the data for the select is ready.

This means two things:

1. When the code in the `$watch` gets executed for this element, the `ngModel` will already be available, both `newValue` and `oldValue` will be `Object {Description: "1"}`, and the `if statement` will not be executed.
2. If you tried to call `element.selectmenu('refresh');` it would throw
   an error, as the element has not yet been initialized as a
   select menu by jQuery Mobile.

If you want to populate the select menu with data from the `$scope` and the data is available at time of initialization, I would:

1. Tell jQuery Mobile not to automatically turn the select into a select menu by setting `data-role="none"`
2. Turn in into a select menu manually by calling `element.selectmenu();` from the directive

Otherwise you would need a good way to know when the element has been rendered and initialized by jQuery Mobile, then call refresh.

Modified directive for both cases:

```
var unbindInitializationWatch = scope.$watch(attrs.ngModel, function(newValue, oldValue) {
        if (newValue && oldValue === undefined) {
          element.selectmenu('refresh');
          unbindInitializationWatch();
        } else if (newValue && oldValue) {
          element.selectmenu();
          unbindInitializationWatch();
        }
      });
```

Working example: http://plnkr.co/edit/9jR7ko3j8ugUr1suB8ws?p=preview

Note that `ngSwitch` creates a new scope, and in order for the both select menus to share selected option I have in the example moved the model for the selected option into an object (More on this [here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DTx23w4z6Kc) if not familiar with how it works).

Also added an additional `$watch` to sync the both select menus.